# How to display only the current page number in angular pagination?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

HTML :

```
<!-- pagination controls -->
<div class="pagination-container">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [maxSize]="1" [id]="config.id" [directionLinks]="true"></pagination-controls>
   {{config.currentPage }} 
</div>
```

Current Output:

Here dueto max size its shows last page 7 and 2 is current page

```
<< previous 7 next >> 2
```

Desire Output:

```
<< previous 2 next >>
```

**dont know how do I place 2 instead of 7 ?**

Updated: if I use maxsize 2 or 3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the current output is displaying the previous and next page numbers, with a maximum of 1 page number visible at a time, and also showing the current page number. However, based on the desired output you provided, it seems that you would like to display the previous and next page numbers with the current page number always in the middle.

To achieve this, you can modify the pagination-controls component to set the maxSize property to a value that is greater than 1, such as 3. This will allow for more page numbers to be displayed at once, with the current page number always in the middle.

EDIT:
Try this way:

```
<div class="pagination-container">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [maxSize]="1" [id]="config.id" [directionLinks]="true"></pagination-controls>
  <span> << previous {{config.currentPage - 2}} </span>
  <span> {{config.currentPage}} </span>
  <span> next {{config.currentPage + 2}} >> </span>
</div>
```

With this code, the pagination-controls component will display the previous and next page numbers, along with the current page number in the middle. The maxSize property has been set to 3, which means that up to 3 page numbers will be displayed at once.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, please check the question I have update output from your code.. still having the same issue